# How do you push a string into a List?

Tags: scala, list, append

I'm trying to make a chatbox in scala. When a user will type anything, I want to stack those in a list.

But when I tried to do list += message

It's saying list is a list of string , and messgae is a string. So, it's not adding the string in the list actually.

Is there anyway to push the string in the list? Like in python u can do append??

Comment: **List** in Scala are immutable _(almost everything is immutable)_ instead of mutable like in Python. Thus `+=` creates a new list with the elements added instead of modifying the original list. _(btw, `+=` has terrible performance on **Lists**)_. - I would recommend you start with a basic tutorial that teaches this basic concepts before trying to build something big.

Comment: I'd recommend you to post the exact error you are saying (I assume you are seeing a compile error? otherwise, what do you mean by `It's saying` ? "who" is saying that?).

Answer (score 4):

You have two choices.

A mutable `ListBuffer[String]` ...

```
val ml = collection.mutable.ListBuffer("one","six")
ml += "ten"  //res0: ml.type = ListBuffer(one, six, ten)
```

... or an immutable `List[String]` referenced via a mutable variable.

```
var il = List("two","four")
il = il :+ "five"  //il: List[String] = List(two, four, five)
```

(You could combine them, a mutable variable holding a mutable collection, but that's a bad idea X 2.)